# ASP.Net Trigger user control dropdownlist change from UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I need to trigger an update event in a user control from update panel, but so far I am having some issues. Here is my scenario: 
UC1:

```
    //uc1
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilterControlRow.ascx.cs" Inherits="FilterWebPart.FilterControlRow" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

// other controls
<div runat="server" id="inputFilters" class="inputFilters">
    <asp:Button ID="btnOpenBracket" runat="server" CssClass="filterBracketButton" OnClick="btnOpenBracket_Click" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPropertyNames" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPropertyNames_SelectedIndexChanged"
        ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
        <div class="filterValidator">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLookup" CssClass="filterTxtValue" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
        </div>

</div>
```

when changed the ddlPropertyNames updates the ddlLookup.

UC2:

```
//uc2
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilterControlNew.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="FilterWebPart.FilterControlNew" ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>
<%@ Register Src="FilterWebPart.FilterControlRow.ascx" TagName="FilterControlRow" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelFilter" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnInit="UpdatePanelFilter_OnInit">
    <ContentTemplate>
        //other controls
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
                OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="filterRow">
                        <uc2:filtercontrolrow id="FilterControlRow1" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" OnClick="btnFind_Click" CssClass="filterButton" Text="Find" 
                ViewStateMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="Filter" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="filterButton" Text="Add" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
        </asp:Panel>
      // more controls
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFind" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

UC2 just contains the first user control in a repeater so I can have multiple filters. and then in the default page I have:

```
<uc1:filtercontrolnew id="WebPartFilter" runat="server" />
```

The main problem is that the first user control was doing a full page postback and I want to avoid that and limit it only to update the dropdown that is inside the usercontrol. I saw somewhere that the UpdatePanel is the way to go, but after many attempts either it does nothing or it is doing a full page postback again. Maybe I am wrapping the update panels wrong, but unfortunatelly I do not have much experience using them.
Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

**First Step** use asynchronous postback trigger, and add the Event Name

```
  //uc2
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilterControlNew.ascx.cs"
        Inherits="FilterWebPart.FilterControlNew" ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>
    <%@ Register Src="FilterWebPart.FilterControlRow.ascx" TagName="FilterControlRow" TagPrefix="uc2" %>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelFilter" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnInit="UpdatePanelFilter_OnInit">
        <ContentTemplate>
            //other controls
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" 
                    OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="filterRow">
                            <uc2:filtercontrolrow id="FilterControlRow1" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <asp:Button ID="btnFind" runat="server" OnClick="btnFind_Click" CssClass="filterButton" Text="Find" 
                    ViewStateMode="Enabled" ValidationGroup="Filter" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" CssClass="filterButton" Text="Add" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
            </asp:Panel>
          // more controls
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFind" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Second Step** add if(! isPostback) in Page_Load and place in it all the code you want not to be refreshed on postback

*Note you should add in the update panel triggers for each tool you are using as buttons repeaters, etc.. and make sure to add the events you're using*

Comment: The problem is that I want the Find button to do a full page postback, but before that the second dropdownlist needs to be updated from the first one which is currently not happening

Comment: Basically the workflow should be 1) Change the value from the first dropdownlist (ddlPropertyNames) without a full page postback - 2) Update the values in second dropdownlist (without a full page postback) - 3) Find (full page postback)

Comment: Try not to do such approach, because in the future you're going to handle all elements on postback of this button, so try handling the button from postback and after the second dropdownlist get updated from the first one simply refresh the page use Response.Redirect(Request.RawURL); this approach will act like the postback but you're handling every event